# How to solve "npm does not support Node.js v11.3.0" warning after upgrading NodeJs 11 from NodeJs 8?

Tags: node.js, npm, upgrade

Windows Server 12, Node 8 installation. I have installed Node 11 and all `npm` operations show the following warning:

> npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v11.3.0 npm WARN npm You
>   should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we npm WARN npm
>   can't make any promises that npm will work with this version. npm WARN
>   npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7,
>   8, 9. npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at
>   https://nodejs.org/
>   6.4.1

`node -v` shows

> v11.3.0

I have tried the following:

- `npm uninstall -g npm` and repair node using 11.3 installer
- `npm install -g npm`

but I receive the same warming.

I have tried an Angular 7 project and `npm install` seem to work properly, but the warning worries me.

Not sure if it helps, but `where npm` shows the following:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm 
>  
>   C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd 
>   C:\Users{logged in username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm 
>  
>   C:\Users{logged in username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd

**Question:** How to solve "npm does not support Node.js v11.3.0" warning after upgrading NodeJs 11 from NodeJs 8?

Comment: did you run `sudo npm cache clean -f` and then installed maybe? or `npm install -g npm@latest`?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty - cache clean + uninstall + reinstall helped. Thanks.

Comment: cool, let me post it as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes cleaning cache helps.

Do a `sudo npm cache clean -f` before the install.

Maybe you can use `npm i -g npm@latest` and see if it works